# How to create a function log file using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I know that there is a way to save one function log by using QuoWSPlatformCore in Visual Basic:

```
Dim v_oPlatformCore As New QuoWSPlatformCore()
    v_oPlatformCore.LBS_Request_SaveMessageLog("MyClass.method")
```

Can I do it somehow in C# for one method like in the example above?
I am new to C# and would like to do it in the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with "creating a function log file" or what `QuoWSPlatformCore`is, but the equivalent c# of the code you have written is the following:

```
var v_oPlatformCore = new QuoWSPlatformCore();
v_oPlatformCore.LBS_Request_SaveMessageLog("MyClass.method");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of QuoWSPlatformCore.  What is it supposed to do?

The c# equivalent of your VB.NET code is:

```
var v_oPlatformCore = New QuoWSPlatformCore();
v_oPlatformCore.LBS_Request_SaveMessageLog("MyClass.method");
```

Comment: that is the problem... i have just a piece of code with this mechanism. Perhaps, it is something outdated